# How to access Sybase Anywhere 12 database using dart?

Tags: dart, sybase, dart-pub

I'm trying to evaluate dart programming language. Right now I try to figure out if it is possible to access a Sybase Anywhere 12 DB using dart.
I've searched pub.dev (and google in general), but couldn't find anything.
So, does anyone know how to access Sybase Anywhere 12 from dart ?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sybase for almost 15 years, but unless I'm mistaken or change on the part of sybase, it is the Transact SQL protocol which is used to query Sybase.

when I was programming at the time I often had to use the libraries for MS SQL Server.

So, if Transact SQL is still used you can use libraries for MS SQL Server like https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket for example.
But it is necessary to install a windows executable on the server

Another solution place an API between your Flutter application and the SYBASE server

This can easily be done in node.js for example since there are packages to connect to Sybase.